# PyCharm not detecting interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

I am trying to code something in PyCharm (by JetBrains), and it is asking for an interpreter, however, there are no interpreters on the list. I am running 64-bit windows with 64-bit python installed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your computer specifications are irrelevant to the question...

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for [configuring available Python interpreters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open PyCharm, Open Settings, Go To "Project: YourProjectName" -> Project Interpreter, click the Gear right to the Project Interpreter Field, Click "Add Local", search for your python.exe and click OK.